# How to pass a string variable to a command in powershell?

Tags: powershell, docker

I intend to use a powershell variable in a script to pass a string value to a command whereupon the command is executed with the parameters as defined in the string. I have been looking at this for a couple of hours now and I don't see what I am doing wrong. I have simplified as much as I can. In the hope of fresh eyes I attach an image, showing:

a. the script that I am using. It's three lines long.

```
$Parms = "-it amazonlinux2 /bin/sh"
Write-Output "& docker run $Parms"
& docker run $Parms
```

b. the PS command line where I execute the script.

```
PS C:\dev\gamelift\serversdk\build> ./test
```

c. the result of the script's execution

```
& docker run -it amazonlinux2 /bin/sh
unknown shorthand flag: ' ' in - amazonlinux2 /bin/sh
See 'docker run --help'.
```

d. the same command executed immediately at the prompt.

```
PS C:\dev\gamelift\serversdk\build> docker run -it amazonlinux2 /bin/sh
```

e. the result of the prompt command, which is correct

```
sh-4.2#
```

[Image of the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKOVu.png)

What magic is happening so that the Write-Output is not being interpreted as the command? I have tried:

a. `docker run $Parms` (without the &)

b. `& docker run "$Parms"` (in quotes)

c. `$Parms = "amazonlinux2 /bin/sh"` and `& docker run -it $Parms` (different error)

d. `$Parms = "amazonlinux2"` and `& docker run -it $Parms /bin/sh` (works)

e. escaping the hyphen (different error)

f. `$Parms = "-it amazonlinux2 /bin/sh"` and each of `& docker run $($Parms)`, `& docker run ${$Parms}` and `& docker run ${Parms}`

I'm feeling a bit stupid. I can't see how the `Write-Output` is right but the call command is bork. It can't be that hard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Call operator (&) does not [parse strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#call-operator-) so "you cannot use command parameters within a string when you use the call operator". You can, however, pass an array so the following will work:

```
$Parms = "-it amazonlinux2 /bin/sh"
Write-Output "& docker run $Parms"
$myargs = -split $Parms 
& docker run $myargs
```

Alternatively using Invoke-Expression (alias `iex`) will also do the trick e.g.:

```
$Parms = "-it amazonlinux2/bin/sh"
Write-Output "& docker run $Parms"
iex "docker run $Parms"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a frequently asked question, although not well documented.  The call operator parameters work as an array:

```
$Parms = '-it','amazonlinux2','/bin/sh'
Write-Output "& docker run $Parms"
& docker run $Parms
```

I would just run docker directly.

```
docker -it amazonlinux2 /bin/sh
```